# How to use tangle to merge to get a single merged file from original source and change files

Tags: tex-core, web

I'm trying to read and understand the TeX source, but it is difficult to keep track of when I should be reading code from the original file and when I should be reading code from the change file.  I would like to merge these files.

So if I have `tex.web` along with `somechanges.ch` how can I merge these files together to get just one readable web file?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I can only see that the tools `tangle` and `weave` take change files as optional arguments, but I don't see the possibility to automatically add a change file to a web file.

Comment: BTW: do you really want to read the `.web` file? Not the resulting `.tex`/`.pdf` file?

Comment: @dıʞsdoʇ, I need the `.web` file to get the resulting `.tex`, `.pdf` file via `weave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I found a program called `tie` in [CTAN](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/tie.html), which you can use to fully merge change files into the original WEB file.

Once you've done this you can use `weave` to convert to a `.tex`, `.pdf` file of the combined code.